# Perl - Include package from relative path, which includes another package from a relative path?

Tags: perl

I have three files:

~/multiFindBinTest.pl:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/mod2";
use pack2;
```

~/mod1/pack1.pm

```
package pack1;
1;
```

~/mod2/pack2.pm

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../mod1";
use pack1;
package pack2;
1;
```

As you can see, base.pl uses pack2, which in turn uses pack1.  However, this is a demonstration of how NOT to use the FindBin module: when base.pl is executed, pack2 will not be able to locate pack1, because it will retain the value of "$FindBin::Bin" that was gotten from base.pl.

**So my question is simple**: Is there a method in perl to "use" a module which "uses" another module, all based on paths relative to the file which does the "using"?

Comment: Modules should never mess with @INC in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to find the location of a *module* file is to use `__FILE__`. Both `FindBin` and `$0` always refer to the main script file.

For the module, this is the neatest I could come up with. Your solution for the main code is fine, but you could use this alternative there as well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename 'fileparse';
use File::Spec;

my $dir;
BEGIN {
  $dir = (fileparse(File::Spec->rel2abs(__FILE__)))[1];
}
use lib $dir.'../mod1';

use pack1;

package pack2;

1;
```

Comment: I prefer `File::Basename::dirname(Cwd::realpath(__FILE__))`. It supports symbolic links way better.

Comment: @ikegami: I rarely use `Cwd`. I avoided `File::Basename::dirname` as the documentation warns against it, but mistakenly used `File::Basename::fileparse` instead of the recommended `File::Spec->splitpath`. I'll leave it as it is now to avoid confusion

Comment: That you rarely use Cwd is only relevant if it did the same thing as F::S. It doesn't. Cwd resolves symlinks (a good thing) while F::S doesn't. `fileparse` is actually the alternative suggested, not F::S's `splitpath` (though I'm sure both are equally fine).

Comment: @ikegami: It is relevant that I rarely use `Cwd` because that's why it didn't occur to me. Please don't make me regret yet another dialogue with you. And if you read the `File::Basename` docs, it recommends *both* `fileparse` and `splitpath` / `splitdir` in different places, which explains why I chose `fileparse` and thought I had it wrong when I looked back at the docs.

Answer (score 2):

If you know all of the possible library roots, you can just add them on the command line:

```
perl -I~/mod1 -I~/mod2 myscript.pl
```

of you can add them to the PERL5LIB environment variable:

```
export PERL5LIB=~/mod1:~/mod2
```

Either method puts the directories on to the libaray search path.

---

Additonal info:

If you want the individual packages to "declare" where their dependencies live, Perl provides the 'lib' pragma:

```
use lib '/path/to/lib/directory';
```

Comment: That requires the person executing the script to know where all the libraries live.  Is there a way for the packages to specify where to find their dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

The locations of the modules must be in the `@INC` at the moment the `use` statement is compiled. The easiest way would be to add them all in the calling program `Test.pl` like this

```
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../mod1", "$FindBin::Bin/../mod2";
```

then the compilation of all the modules will go ahead fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that, but you could make your own.

```
package libr;

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

sub import { 
    shift; # invoker
    my ( @cands, @missed );

    ARGS:
    while ( @_ ) { 

        # Get the next argument from the queued candidates or from the 
        # arguments
        my $raw_path 
            = my $path 
            = @cands ? shift @cands : shift
            ;

        # We don't need to worry about this argument unless it has relative 
        # notation in it. 
        if ( index( $path, '::' ) > -1 ) { 

            # split it into parts
            my ( $mod, $rest ) = split qr{(?:/(?:\.(?=/))?)+}, $path, 2;
            $mod =~ s/^:://; # Allow for one-word relative nodes: 'Word::/';

            # Move it from mod notation to file...
            my ( $mod_path ) = map { s|::|/|g; $_ } $mod;

            my %set;
            while ( my $len = length $mod_path ) { 

                # Remember the more specific path first
                $set{ $_ } ||= $mod_path
                    foreach 
                        # for each key that qualifies, subtract the same
                        # number of characters from the end of the value
                        map  { substr( $INC{ $_ }, 0, $len - length ) . $rest }

                        # test each key that it starts with our string
                        grep { substr( $_, 0, $len ) eq $mod_path } 

                        keys %INC
                    ;
            }
            continue { 
                # Check if our separator is in the mod path.
                my $mark = rindex( $mod_path, '/' );
                last if $mark == -1;

                # move the unmatched part of the substring to the 
                # ending
                substr( $rest, 0, 0, substr( $mod_path, $mark ));
                # delete it from the path
                substr( $mod_path, $mark ) = '';
            }
            my @sort_order 
                  # We only want the first value...
                = map  { shift @$_ }
                  # sort by length of matching path first, then alphabetically
                  sort { $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] or $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
                  # store a collection of values for sorting: 
                  # lowercase string and length of matching string
                  map  { [ $_ => lc $_ => length $set{ $_ } ] } 
                  keys %set
                ;
            ### Assemble list of candidates
            @cands = ( @sort_order, map { "$_/$mod_path$rest" } @INC );
            next ARGS;
        }

        # If the path exists
        if ( -e $path ) {
            # Store the canonical path
            push @INC, File::Spec->canonpath( $path );
            # And reset tracking arrays
            @cands  = () if @cands;
            @missed = () if @missed;
        }
        elsif ( @cands ) { 
            # If we're trying out values, just remember the missed ones.
            push @missed, $path;
        }
        else { 
            # Else, we're going to tell you we couldn't match the directory
            # either to one or to all candidates we tried.
            Carp::carp( 
                  "A valid path cannot be determined from '$raw_path': "
                . ( @missed > 1  ? do { 
                      local $LIST_SEPARATOR = "\n    - ";
                      push @missed, '', $path;
                      "\n No paths:@missed\n do not exist!";
                    }
                  : "$path does not exist!"
                  ));
            @missed = () if @missed;
        } # end else
    } # end while @_
}
```

Then you use like this:

```
package main;

use A::Long::Package::Name;
use Smart::Comments;

use libr 'A::Long::Package::Name/../Foo', 'Figgy::Puddin';
```

Try dumping out `@INC` after words and see what happened.